# Concatenate values & count rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table like this

[image]

Trying to get the output as below

[image]

The below SQL will do the concatenation of ID2 values for the same ID1. How do I get the count of ID1 based on the number of combinations of ID1,ID2 also?

```
SELECT
ID1,
LISTAGG(ID2, ', ')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID2) "ID2Values"
FROM table_name
```

Comment: Did you try to check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Aggregate-Functions.html#GUID-62BE676B-AF18-4E63-BD14-25206FEA0848)? [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ID1,
     LISTAGG(ID2, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID2) "ID2Values",
     count(*)
FROM table_name
group by ID1
```